# In my react hooks the display of record based on latest date is not happening

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, momentjs

I would like to display the latest record based on `date` on top of the list in my `react hooks` app. By using moment.js, will it automatically sort the latest record on top of the list ? Could someone please advise how can we achieve that ?

CSB link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-cache-dkt924?file=/src/App.js:156-1140

```
const data = [
  {
    name: "Apple",
    type: "Fruit",
    date: "2022-06-10T05:49:24.000Z"
  },
  {
    name: "Beans",
    type: "Vegtables",
    date: "2022-07-10T10:49:24.000Z"
  },
  {
    name: "Oranges",
    type: "Fruit",
    date: "2022-05-10T07:49:24.000Z"
  }
];
export default function App() {
  const [fruitData, setFruitsData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setFruitsData(data);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="column">
        <h2>Latest Data</h2>

        <div className="announcebox" id="style-7">
          {fruitData.map(({ id, name, date }) => (
            <div key={id}>
              <div className="newsDate">
                {moment(date).format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss")}
              </div>
              <p>
                <div className="annoucement updates">{name}</div>
              </p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your useEffect to this

```
useEffect(() => {
    data.sort(function(a,b){
      return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
    });
    setFruitsData(data);
  }, []);
```